# Question about rockabilly piano technique

Tags: piano

I used to play piano when I was younger, but never really got anywhere with it. now im trying to pick it back up and im not doing too bad. My only problem is, and I have searched youtube etc etc..is I am having difficulty getting the correct right hand notes for some songs. I can find the chords on the internet or something, but the right hand is not difficult I don't believe, it just sounds like there are different notes put in periodically. for example the following song here:

[Harold Lee-Blond Headed Woman 1959](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNSKdx8Mpiw)

The piano solo is literally boggling to me. I'm not really sure how you do the LH the beat is odd, but the right hand is really bothering me. I can give chords or whatever if anyone knows how to help me figure out how to learn a melody to this type of song. Thanks.

Comment: Can you narrow down the question to a specific thing on the song, what minute:second? How have you tried playing it, and what aspects of it have you not been able to reproduce? To me it sounds like a basic rockabilly piano solo, banging on 1/8 notes, and an occasional triplet, most of the time slightly dragging behind the beat.

Comment: @piiperi The thing is, if the question is about what notes to play for a specific part of a specific song, then it's off-topic. I think the real thrust of the question as it is comes down to, how do you embellish a chord progression on piano in a way that fits the rockabilly style?

Comment: @ToddWilcox To me the question appears to be about "rockabilly piano technique", like, how to do stuff like what the pianist does in this example song. Form the text I couldn't figure out what it is that the OP can't get going. "Tell me everything about rockabilly" would probably get flagged offside too.

Comment: @piiperi - sounds on the beat to me. Good ol' 12 bar.

Comment: @Tim ok maybe, but at least it sounds better if you drag and swing. If you have a suitable MIDI sequencer, try delaying a steady quantized 1/8th rockabilly piano rhythm by 20-30 ms, you'll notice a difference. IMO it sounds "heavier" and groovier it's slightly behind the beat. And add some swing too: even 1/8ths can drag more.

Answer (score 2):

It's a standard boogie style rockabilly. Played much like Jerry Lee Lewis would play, minus the right heel on the keyboard. The right hand is doing mostly 16th note switches from the two note chords of in the upper register of the piano. notes are "a,d" "a,d" "a,e" "a,d" for the chord running against the left hands bass walk style. The LHand is walking  down in quarter note progression. Those note are "A" down "F#" down "E" then back up "F#" up to "A" and back down again up and down walk. Start the down from A and continue.
Those two hands together is for the A chord in the key of A. Use the same thing when doing the Chords D and the E. Get this down and you will start finding the steps from one chord to the others. So, in short your RHand is 16th notes and the LHand is 1/4 notes.